# Set DisplayFor DataAnnotation in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I want to mask all but the last 4 of the social. (Before everyone goes nuts over this, the data in this particular table is subject to federal regulatory guidelines so we are not permitted to alter the raw data.) I this is a simple view only page and I don't want to add DisplayAttributes in the entity model. I have tried the below, but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => string.Format(item.SSN, "{0:***-**-0000}" ))
```

Comment: how about creating a separate template for that and then call `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.SSN, "yourtemplate")` ?

Comment: `I this is a simple view only page and I don't want to add DisplayAttributes in the entity model` - that's your **root problem**: you are using an entity model instead of a view model. So I would suggest you resolving your root problem before going nuts with this.

Comment: Wont that apply the formatting to all strings since SSN is a string?